# Dynamic Routes not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am having trouble getting dynamic routes to work in Laravel 4

**Routes**

```
Route::any('/browse/{$id}', 'BrowseController@showProfile');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

class BrowseController extends BaseController {

    public function showProfile($id)
    {
        return $car_id;
    }
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8000/browse/10018`

I receive a not found error

[image]

Any Idea what is wrong? Sorry I am new to Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `$` in the variable name in your route. Try using

```
Route::any('/browse/{id}', 'BrowseController@showProfile');
```

Also, you should add validation to only allow numbers:

```
Route::any('/browse/{id}', 'BrowseController@showProfile')->where('id', '\d+');
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't catch that. Sorry!

Comment: New Problem! I have my route set as Route::any('browse/{car_id}', 'BrowseController@showProfile');      In my blade view I have: HTML::linkRoute('browse/'.$car->car_id, 'Car ID: '.$car->car_id);  I receive the error Route [browse/10018] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\car\app\views\car\browse.blade.php)

Comment: Please create a new question for this problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in {$id}, try only {id}